# Organize views and controllers with the new EmberJS router

Tags: view, controller, ember.js, router

I want to organize my views in packages / folders to avoid a long list. With the (great) new router, a view is provided by default that we can change by creating a new one with a convention name. For example:

```
match('/').to('home');
```

uses:

- "home" handlebars template
- App.HomeView
- App.HomeController

Now I want to use:

- "my_package/home" handlebars template (works)
- App.MyPackage.HomeView
- App.MyPackage.HomeController

When I use the gem "ember-rails" (the GIT version) and the generator:

```
rails g ember:view my_package/home
```

I get:

```
DemoEmberRails.MyPackage::HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
});
```

that is not a correct javascript code (seems to be an extract for ruby code).

I tried:

```
DemoEmberRails.MyPackage = {};
DemoEmberRails.MyPackage.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
});
```

But it's not used by the router.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Namespace them using Ember.Namespace. I'm still not sure if the router will automatically search namespaces but it may?

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Namespace.html

Comment: I try to create a namespace App.MyPackage just after the definition of the application, but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's possible that you may have to define a separate router per namespace. App.MyPackage.Router. Ember.Application is just an extended version of Ember.Namespace itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you've said

```
match('/').to('home');
```

expects `AppName.HomeRoute`, `AppName.HomeView` and `AppName.HomeController`. So if you have a template with `data-template-name="home"` and a view similar to

```
AppName.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  teplateName: 'home'
});
```

then ember will automatically connect the `/` route with this view.

The new [ember routing guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) are quite helpful here.

Comment: I would have App. **MyPackage** .HomeX, and not just App.HomeX to group views and controllers by package.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is currently unsupported, however, a pull request exists to add this feature.

See:
 https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1679

Comment: That pull request has been rejected.